# Selecting SQL Column from Value of Parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table containing columns titles like CR_Name, CV_Name, IC_Name.  I am trying to write a query so that if the @p parameter is set to 'CR', my select query will pull the CR_Name column as well as any other column I want that starts with CR.

I have tried the below and it has failed.  Is it possible and if so how?

```
declare @p char(2) = 'CR'

select
@p_name  --I want this to be the 'CR_name' column
from table
where @p_status = 0 --I want this to be the CR_status column
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: This sounds like an "X/Y problem"... Why do you want to choose what columns to retrieve at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accomplish that by use of *dynamic SQL*.

```
create table dbo.Table1
(
    CR_Name nvarchar(50), 
    CV_Name nvarchar(50), 
    IC_Name nvarchar(50),
    CR_Text nvarchar(50)
)

-- declare parameters
declare @p char(2) = 'CR';
declare @p1 TABLE
(
  param char(3)
);
insert into @p1
values (concat(@p,'%'));

-- create the skeleton of your query
declare @skeleton nvarchar(max) =

'SELECT <cols>
 FROM dbo.table1 AS t;';

-- dynamically get the columns from the table metadata in sql server
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (
select
    REPLACE(@skeleton, '<cols>', cols.cols)
from
    sys.objects so
    inner join
    sys.tables ta on so.object_id = ta.object_id
    inner join
    sys.schemas sc on ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
cross apply
(
    select
      string_agg('t.[' + cols.name + ']',', ') as cols
    from
      sys.columns cols
        left join sys.index_columns ic on ic.index_column_id = cols.column_id and ic.object_id = cols.object_id
        left join sys.indexes idx on ic.index_id = idx.index_id and idx.object_id = cols.object_id
-- here we decide, which columns to pick
        inner join @p1 para on cols.name like para.param 
    where
      cols.object_id = so.object_id
) cols (cols)
where
    so.name = 'table1' and so.type = 'U' and sc.name = 'dbo');
```

the main difficulty here is to also include the dynamic column filter clause, because you do not want an exact match, but instead a LIKE behaviour

Then you can just execute the query by using:

```
-- DEBUG
--print(@sql);

--TSA: execute the generated statement
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parameterise identifiers in T-SQL without using Dynamic SQL (aka *generating-SQL-from-string-concatenation* which is inherently dangerous). Just select all the columns anyway and change the read logic in your application code.

I note that selecting columns in a query is really cheap (unless it's a large binary column, like `varbinary(8000)` or something).

Your question also asks about conditional `WHERE` clauses. Unfortunately (as of March 2019, to my knowledge) SQL Server's query optimizer still does not correctly optimize-away certain patterns, like the match-always-if-parameter-is-null pattern, but if your table isn't high-load then it might be okay.

Like so:

```
DECLARE @param1 int         = NULL
DECLARE @param2 varchar(50) = 'john smith'
DECLARE @param3 float       = 123

SELECT
    CR_name,
    CV_name,
    IC_name
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ( @param1 IS NULL OR CR_name = @param1 )
    AND
    ( @param2 IS NULL OR CV_name = @param2 )
    AND
    ( @param3 IS NULL OR IC_name = @param3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is highly unrecommended, and suggests you may have a serious flaw in your schema design. If you provide more details, someone may be able to suggest alternatives. To answer your question, you can try something like:

```
declare @p char(2) = 'CR', @SQL VARCHAR(4000);

    SET @SQL = 
    'select ' 
    + @p 
    + '_name from table where ' 
    + @p + '_status = 0;' 

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

HTH